# I need help at my table structure which is many to many relationship

Tags: mysql

Is it necessary to create a bridge table for many-many relationship table?

for example:

`Table Group` will have a column for blocked websites for each group and each group can have more than 1 blocked websites

Lets say, `Group One` will have `facebook.com and twitter.com` blocked now the look of it in the column will be `"Blocked_Websites"` will have the value of `facebook.com,twitter.com` inside its row. This way I can retrieve this via php and just explode it to display in a page (page to display blocked websites for each group)

but is this alright? or should I use bridge table for this?

Because most or always, people use bridge table for many to many relationship.

Comment: Can you provide what have you try till now for achieve that?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Oh.. I'm sorry for that... It was a habit to use "for example" word which is my mistake.. it is as I said.. I have "Groups" table which have a column "Blocked Websites" which have row that contain many websites separated by comma (which is working)... after I have search for relationships (was plannign to use FK).. I came across "many-many" ... 

Now I am confused if it is better to use "Bridge Table" for this... or just stick to my current structure... so I asked for some advice on it..

Comment: Yes. In general, and at present, if using an RDBMS then it's best to adopt the forms of normalisation- at least up to 3NF

Comment: thanks :) ... I'll will look up and learn normalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In general having **many-to-many relationship** is a bad design.

As you said, try to use a bridge table like which gives a one-to-many relationship. Using this standard while structuring, makes it easy to maintain in the future

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot for this :)